# How to highlight a window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I'm working with JavaFX drag-n-drop file imports and I want the entire window (client area) to highlight blue whenever the user drags files over it. I know how to use the JavaFX input API and CSS just fine but don't know an easy way to do this. Is it possible to put a mask over the window, or will I just have to go through changing the background color of the root and every node? I want something like this (Mac window screenshot highlighting):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a suitably-styled `Region`, make it unmanaged and mouse transparent, and add it to the root pane. If you need, observe the bounds of the root pane and resize the region to fill it.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightWholeWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Region mask = createMask();
        ToggleButton highlightButton = new ToggleButton("Highlight");
        highlightButton.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasHighlighted, isNowHighlighted) -> {
            Pane root = (Pane)highlightButton.getScene().getRoot();
            if (isNowHighlighted) {
                root.getChildren().add(mask);
            } else {
                root.getChildren().remove(mask);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(highlightButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Region createMask() {
        Region mask = new Region();

        // in real life, use an external style sheet:
        mask.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6495ed80;");

        mask.setManaged(false);
        mask.setMouseTransparent(true);
        mask.setLayoutX(0);
        mask.setLayoutY(0);

        ChangeListener<Bounds> boundsListener = (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> 
            mask.resizeRelocate(newBounds.getMinX(), newBounds.getMinY(),
                                newBounds.getWidth(), newBounds.getHeight());

        mask.parentProperty().addListener((obs, oldParent, newParent) -> {
            if (oldParent != null) {
                oldParent.boundsInLocalProperty().removeListener(boundsListener);
            }
            if (newParent != null) {
                Bounds newParentBounds = newParent.getBoundsInLocal() ;
                mask.resizeRelocate(newParentBounds.getMinX(), newParentBounds.getMinY(), 
                                    newParentBounds.getWidth(), newParentBounds.getHeight());
                newParent.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(boundsListener);
            }
        });

        return mask ;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can adapt this to respond to drag handlers instead of the toggle button.

[image]

[image]